# ElementTree Returns Element Instead of ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to build an *ElementTree* from a string. When I do the following (as set out in [Python ElementTree: Parsing a string and getting ElementTree instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580234/python-elementtree-parsing-a-string-and-getting-elementtree-instance/%20Python%20ElementTree:%20Parsing%20a%20string%20and%20getting%20ElementTree%20instance%22)), I get an *Element* instead of an *ElementTree*:

```
companyTree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring('<companies></companies>'))
```

If I do

```
print(companyTree.getroot())
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

In other words, companyTree is an *Element* instead of an *ElementTree*. According to the accepted answer in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580234/python-elementtree-parsing-a-string-and-getting-elementtree-instance/%20Python%20ElementTree:%20Parsing%20a%20string%20and%20getting%20ElementTree%20instance%22), I should be getting an ElementTree. Has the API changed? How do I get an ElementTree from a string now? Thanks.

Note that there is more on this problem in [Python ElementTree: ElementTree vs root Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620254/python-elementtree-elementtree-vs-root-element)

Comment: and how are `root` and `companyTree` related?

Comment: Yea, that was a bit unclear. the companyTree = root (passed to a method with root). Edited.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Executing `print(companyTree.getroot())` prints out `<Element 'companies' at 0x009B1630>`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There was an error in the function that was passed the ElementTree and that caused the exception above. Thanks.

Answer (score 67):

This one bit me too.  I had some old code kicking around that used `parse()`.  I refactored to use `fromstring()`, causing the same error. 
 Based on your references, I can summarize what's going on here; I believe this will be beneficial for people getting this specific error.  The other articles deal directly with the API itself so I wouldn't consider them duplicates.

So, first to address [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580234/python-elementtree-parsing-a-string-and-getting-elementtree-instance/%20Python%20ElementTree:%20Parsing%20a%20string%20and%20getting%20ElementTree%20instance%22).  You are correct that the stated issue is related, however I don't think the accepted answer is making the claim that `fromstring()` is supposed to return an `ElementTree`.  Rather, the author of this answer is saying *in the context of the problem* the string is equivalent to a complete XML document rather than a fragment, so it's *appropriate* to convert it to an `ElementTree`:

> When you use ElementTree.fromstring() what you're getting back is basically the root of the tree, so if you create a new tree like this ElementTree.ElementTree(root) you'll get you're looking for.

And in his code sample, he does just that:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(<your_xml_string>))
```

This approach is confirmed by the [second reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620254/python-elementtree-elementtree-vs-root-element) you posted, which links an old article by the library's author, in which he states (and I paraphrase) that this is not a design quirk, it's a feature. The expectation is that constructs like `parse()` are designed to work with complete documents and `fromstring()` is designed to work with fragments **and** documents.  It's just in this latter case that we the programmer must resolve the ambiguity and inform the library that we *expect* the string to be a complete document.

So, as far as my use case goes, I had a complete document in my XML string and wanted the `ElementTree` features, so I wrapped my `fromstring()` call in an `ElementTree` as in the example above.

Comment: Incredibly useful answer!  Don't know why no other up-votes.

Comment: Yes this answer saved me a lot of time. Well detailed explanation!

Comment: I would consider your answer as the accepted answer. I hope the OP do so

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this in 2023, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), you can either do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

where `.parse()` returns ElementTree, or:

```
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

which returns the root directly. So there's no need to call `.getroot()`.